# NoSuchMethodError: Class 'List<Data> has no instance getter

Tags: flutter, dependencies, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I have gridviewbuilder that takes data from itemGriddata which has onTap function that directs it to a new page that takes data from that model as well but when I click on it the error in the title appears, any help or some kind of enlightement would be appreciated

this is gridview page

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:wild_wild_rift/builds/SinglePage.dart';
import 'package:wild_wild_rift/data/model.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

class GridViewPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _GridViewPage createState() => _GridViewPage();
}

class _GridViewPage extends State<GridViewPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
          automaticallyImplyLeading: true,
          title: const Text(
            'Champions',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontFamily: 'Lexend Doca',
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 32,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
          elevation: 2,
        ),
        body: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(15, 15, 15, 15),
                child: GridView.builder(
                  itemCount: itemGriddata.length,
                  gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    crossAxisCount: 4,
                    crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                    mainAxisSpacing: 10,
                    childAspectRatio: 1,
                  ),
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return GridSingleItem(
                      itemGriddata: itemGriddata[index],
                      onTap: () async {
                        Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => SinglePage(itemGriddata[index])));
                      },
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }
}

class GridSingleItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final itemGriddata;
  final Function onTap;

  const GridSingleItem({Key key, @required this.itemGriddata, this.onTap})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: onTap,
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
        child: Container(
          width: 100,
          height: 100,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: const Color(0xEEEEEE),
            image: DecorationImage(
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              image: Image.asset(itemGriddata.image).image,
            ),
            boxShadow: const [
              BoxShadow(
                blurRadius: 3,
                color: Color(0xDA000000),
              )
            ],
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(9),
            border: Border.all(
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
          ),
          child: Align(
            alignment: AlignmentDirectional(-0.45, 0.85),
            child: Text(
              itemGriddata.name,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: 'Lexend Deca',
                color: Color(0xFFFFFCFC),
                fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                shadows: [
                  Shadow(
                    blurRadius: 8.0,
                    color: Colors.black,
                    offset: Offset(1.0, 1.0),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

this is page that I'd want to take data

```
import 'package:auto_size_text/auto_size_text.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../data/model.dart';

class SinglePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SinglePage createState() => _SinglePage();
  final Data data;
  SinglePage(this.data);
}

class _SinglePage extends State<SinglePage> {
  PageController pageViewController;
  bool isFirstButton = false;
  bool isSecondButton = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    pageViewController = PageController(initialPage: 0);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF090F13),
        automaticallyImplyLeading: true,
        title: Text(
          itemGriddata.name,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'Lexend Deca',
            color: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 32,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
        actions: const [],
        centerTitle: false,
        elevation: 2,
      ),
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF262D34),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(0, 0, 0, 25),
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                      children: [
                        Material(
                          color: Colors.transparent,
                          elevation: 3,
                          child: Container(
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                            height: 150,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: const Color(0xFF090F13),
                              image: DecorationImage(
                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                image: Image.asset(
                                  itemGriddata.backgroundimage,
                                ).image,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding:
                          const EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(20, 12, 20, 0),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                        children: const [
                          Text(
                            'Choose role',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: 'Lexend Deca',
                              color: Color(0xFF8B97A2),
                              fontSize: 14,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding:
                          const EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(0, 12, 1, 0),
                      child: SingleChildScrollView(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                          children: [
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(
                                  16, 0, 0, 0),
                              child: InkWell(
                                onTap: () async {
                                  isSecondButton = false;
                                  isFirstButton = true;
                                  setState(() {});
                                  await pageViewController.animateToPage(
                                    0,
                                    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                                    curve: Curves.ease,
                                  );
                                },
                                child: Material(
                                  color: Colors.transparent,
                                  elevation: 2,
                                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                                  ),
                                  child: Container(
                                    width: 100,
                                    height: 100,
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        color: const Color(0xFF090F13),
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                                        shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                                        border: isFirstButton
                                            ? Border.all(color: Colors.white)
                                            : null),
                                    child: Stack(
                                      children: [
                                        Align(
                                          alignment: const AlignmentDirectional(
                                              0, -0.05),
                                          child: Column(
                                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                            mainAxisAlignment:
                                                MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                            children: [
                                              Image.asset(
                                                'assets/images/icon-position-jungle.png',
                                                width: 50,
                                                height: 50,
                                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                              ),
                                              const Padding(
                                                padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional
                                                    .fromSTEB(0, 8, 0, 0),
                                                child: AutoSizeText(
                                                  'BUILD 1',
                                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                    fontFamily: 'Lexend Deca',
                                                    color: Color(0xFF8B97A2),
                                                    fontSize: 14,
                                                    fontWeight:
                                                        FontWeight.normal,
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(
                                  16, 0, 0, 0),
                              child: Material(
                                color: Colors.transparent,
                                elevation: 2,
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                                ),
                                child: Container(
                                  width: 100,
                                  height: 100,
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      color: const Color(0xFF090F13),
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                                      border: isSecondButton
                                          ? Border.all(color: Colors.white)
                                          : null),
                                  child: InkWell(
                                    onTap: () async {
                                      isSecondButton = true;
                                      isFirstButton = false;
                                      setState(() {});
                                      await pageViewController.animateToPage(
                                        1,
                                        duration:
                                            const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                                        curve: Curves.ease,
                                      );
                                    },
                                    child: Stack(
                                      children: [
                                        Align(
                                          alignment: const AlignmentDirectional(
                                              0, -0.05),
                                          child: Column(
                                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                            mainAxisAlignment:
                                                MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                            children: [
                                              Image.asset(
                                                'assets/images/icon-position-jungle.png',
                                                width: 50,
                                                height: 50,
                                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                              ),
                                              const Padding(
                                                padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional
                                                    .fromSTEB(0, 8, 0, 0),
                                                child: AutoSizeText(
                                                  'BUILD 2',
                                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                    fontFamily: 'Lexend Deca',
                                                    color: Color(0xFF8B97A2),
                                                    fontSize: 14,
                                                    fontWeight:
                                                        FontWeight.normal,
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding:
                          const EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(20, 8, 20, 8),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                        children: const [
                          Text(
                            'Builds',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: 'Lexend Deca',
                              color: Color(0xFF8B97A2),
                              fontSize: 14,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    SingleChildScrollView(
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                        children: [
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(
                                16, 8, 16, 0),
                            child: Container(
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                              height: 200,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: const Color(0x00090F13),
                                boxShadow: const [
                                  BoxShadow(
                                    blurRadius: 3,
                                    color: Colors.transparent,
                                    offset: Offset(0, 2),
                                  )
                                ],
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                              ),
                              child: SizedBox(
                                width: double.infinity,
                                height: 500,
                                child: PageView(
                                  controller: pageViewController,
                                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                  children: [
                                    Image.asset(
                                      'assets/images/image_1.png',
                                      width: 100,
                                      height: 100,
                                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                    ),
                                    Image.asset(
                                      'assets/images/image_2.png',
                                      width: 100,
                                      height: 100,
                                      fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(20, 0, 20, 8),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                children: const [
                  Text(
                    'Text',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                      color: Color(0xFF8B97A2),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and this is the model with data

```
final dynamic itemGriddata = [
  Data(
      name: "Ahri",
      image: "assets/images/Ahri.png",
      backgroundimage: "assets/images/Ahri_0.jpg"),
  Data(
      name: "Akali",
      image: "assets/images/Akali.png",
      backgroundimage: "assets/images/Akali_0.jpg")
];

class Data {
  final String name;
  final String image;
  final String backgroundimage;

  Data({this.name, this.image, this.backgroundimage});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that your SinglePage widget has a prop named `final Data data;` but the _SinglePageState widget is calling `itemGriddata` for your title and images. You'll need to change your code like so:

```
class SinglePage extends StatefulWidget {

  const SinglePage(Key? key, this.data): super(key: key);

  final Data data;

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _SinglePageState();

}

class _SinglePageState extends State<SinglePage> {

  // use widget.data to get name, image, and backgroundImage
  // ex... widget.data.name or widget.data.image

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(widget.data.name);
  }
}
```

You're passing the data correctly to SinglePage, but just change a few lines to ensure you're calling something with actual data! :D

Comment: State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _SinglePageState();  this is what I was missing, thank you so much good Sir ! :D